SQL CMD EXPORT data issue
I'm trying to export data into csv using sqlcmd , there are my parameters -h -1 -y 8000 -w 8000 -s",".
Issue I'm facing is the last column of exported data is too long, i mean last column width is too long and
data in it having more trailing spaces.  I have checked the data in DB it has no spaces only when exporting
using sqlcmd i'm facing this issue . I tried changing the parameters values but still it is not solved.
Please help to solve this issue.
I tried changing the parameter values of sqlcmd but it still unsolved.
I need to proper formatted data with column width adjusted and data with no spaces.
